# Rats - dealing with what appears to be a colony of them

Tags: pest-control, pest

Appears that we have a a large amount of rats that have taken to forming a complex tunnel system in a small patch of ground between the alley and our garage. There is an old stump, whose submerged root structure probably has formed a great little cavern for them.

We have had both the city and a private pest control service come and try to resolve, but so far smoke and poison has not been effective, and closing their access has only created really pissed off rodents that blast bigger holes.

We have not gotten to the point of removing any of the dirt for further investigation, so its unclear how much of a system they have created under the garage.

Assuming we can get rid of this set of rats, any recommendations for making that area less permeable for the next wave would be appreciated.

In addition, we have gone about to ensure the shared alley is as clean as possible, and for the most part there doesnt appear to be blatant rat/rodent attractions (debry, animal waste, etc) -- but there is only so much you can change in a city alley.

Thank you for helping fight the good fight!

Comment: Trap and kill would be my only relevant suggestion on eliminating them, which is such a small component of your overall question that it does not seem answer-worthy. If it's truly a large number, you might want a trash-can sized version of the "can with peanut butter spinning on a wire over a deep, smooth-sided bucket of water to drown them in" repeating trap.

Comment: 1-800-stump-removal. Then we'll see.

Comment: Sounds like book 2 for Stephen King...

Comment: Yeah after you remove the stump maybe you can have minks go after them. Check out how good they are at killing rats. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iaAYnRvHhGI

Comment: Stump is most likely coming out this weekend

Answer (score 2):

If you're not squeamish, a trash can with a diving board and a pool of water in the bottom will kill hundreds of rats with low effort.

Actual trap: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Original-Dunk-The-Rat-Trap-Rat-Squirrel-Trap-Auto-Reset-USA-MADE/132422341963?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2055119.m1438.l2649

Review/setup: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfaDQJVplYI

[image]

Comment: I had not seen that one before, it may work better than the spinning can because they feel secure walking the plank until the magnet breaks loose.+

Comment: I love this ...